# Как в Delphi сохранять данных в Word файл в нужное место?

Tags: delphi, ms-word, office

Мне для программы нужно создать экзаменационный билет. Для этого мне нужно ввести в программе, написанной на Delphi, Имя, Фамилию, Предмет, Вариант и Год, и чтобы это сохранилось вместе с вариантами ответа в файл Word на местах, которые я указал.

Можно ли так сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**вот примерно так выглядеть должно**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё какие компоненты нужны для этого?

Comment: в ворде на вкладке Разработчик, есть Элементы управления содрежимым, т.ч. текстовые, рисунки и еще что то. К таким элементам можно  добавить название и тэг. Вот по тэгу эти элементы можно искать (`SelectContentControlsByTag`) и заменять значения.

Comment: @teran О ней мало кто знает :) Плюс, она появилась, начиная с Офиса 2007, а в некоторых сферах принципиально сидят на 2003.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov ну это так, ради коммента написано. на ответ не тянет, но чтобы частица знаний осталась под этим вопросом. но штука удобная. я с помощью таких блоков динамически документацию к продукту собирал в зависимости от модулей, которые были у заказчика, заменял картинки в документе для каждого конкретного клиента. без делфей, конечно, на вба в самом доке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. При этом, думаю, можно обойтись и без сторонних компонентов.
Проще всего создать шаблон будущего документа, в котором текст уже будет размещен **на нужных местах**. Тогда вашей задачей будет всего лишь заменить его на свой. Инициализируете OleObject (разумеется, Word должен быть установлен!):

```
var
  Word : variant;
<...>
     try
          Word := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
     except
          MessageBox ('Не установлен Microsoft Word!!!', 'Ошибка',
                              MB_OK);
          exit;
     end;
     word.documents.open ('Путь к документу\Имя.docx'); // открываем ваш файл
     word.Visible := false; // спрячем его с экрана
```

Если делать всё по-честному, то теперь нужно работать с коллекциями Word через `Word.Documents.Item`, т.е. к примеру, чтобы обратиться к 1й колонке последней таблицы (если у вас есть в документе таблицы), нужно делать так:

```
W1.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(W1.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count).Columns.Item(1).Select;
```

Сразу дам подсказку: чтобы потом не мучаться с перебором коллекций, один раз сделать эту замену руками при включенной записи макроса (Сервис/Макрос/Начать запись...), тогда вы будете знать, к каким коллекциям обращаться.

Ну, а теперь немного "шулерства".

```
  procedure FindAndReplace (ww:variant; SearchStr, ReplaceStr : string);
  begin
    ww.Selection.Find.Text := SearchStr;
    ww.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text := ReplaceStr;
    ww.Selection.Find.Execute (Replace := 2);
  end;
<...>
  FindAndReplace (Word, '%prepod%', edit1.Text); // просто ищем  в документе предопределенный текст и заменяем его.
  FindAndReplace (Word, '%bilet%', edit2.Text);
  FindAndReplace (Word, '%DATE%', edit3.Text);
```

В сети много информации по работе с документами Office, рекомендую поизучать, откроете массу полезного.

Ну, а если уж совсем лениво, вот бесплатный компонент [VectorSoft Report](http://www.vector-ski.com/reports/arwordreport_index.htm), позволяющий при небольшом старании создавать на базе готового шаблона нужный вам документ.

Comment: дак и фастрепорт, входящий в стандартную поставку, позволит сохранить. в rtf, правда, наверное, но не суть

Comment: @teran Если просто для печати - не суть, а у нас, к примеру, электронные билеты принимают только в DOC. Казалось бы, в чём проблема - переименовать RTF в DOC, и все дела. Ан нет: программа проверки, видимо, проверяет заголовок или ещё что-то, ругается на RTF